# Rewriting over int value in int subclass impossible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, subclass

I am currently on a python 3 project in witch I work a lot with binary representation of ints, because of this, I made a classe to make the work easier for myself, but I can't make it fully work :

```
class EnhancedInt(int):
    def __init__(self, x: Union[str, bytes, SupportsInt] = ...) -> None:
        int.__init__(int(x))

    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> int:
        """Returns the digit number key from the binary representation of self  (little endian)

        Args:
            key (int):

        Returns:
            int:
        """
        if key > 32:
            raise ValueError("int are 32 bits long, %d given is too much" % key)
        if key < 0:
            raise ValueError("Negative keys not supported, %d given is too low" % key)
        else:
            return EnhancedInt((self >> key) & 1)

    def __setitem__(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
        if value != 0 and value != 1:
            raise ValueError('Value must be 0 or 1')
        self -= self[key]*pow(2, key)
        if value:
            self += pow(2, key)
```

So, the part that's not working : `__setitem__`. I understand why, changing `self` seems a bit brutal, but I can't find where the value is stored in an int.

For additional comprehension, here is the code calling my class :

```
>>> i = EnhancedInt(5)
>>> print(i[1])
0
>>> i[1] = 1
>>> print(i)
5 ????
```

I would like for 7 to be returned, but for now, only 5 is returned.

Comment: You are subclassing an immutable type, so you *can't* modify that part of it.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from int when it looks like you're trying to implement what looks to be a collection type? Store your int a `__slots__` thing and operate on it if you want but either way this looks overly complicated.

Comment: here, I only showed the collection pat, but I intend tu use these as int. I need all the properties that you would usually have with an int (for example, i want so be able to do `i, j = EnhancedInt(5), EnhancedInt(7)`
and then `k = i + j`, instead of `k = i._slot_ + j._slot_`)

Comment: You are not actually changing the instance.  You're just rebinding the name "self" as a local variable.

Comment: Since int is immutable, and you want a mutable class, this is not a good case for inheritance - consider composition instead ("has a" int instead of "is a" int).

Comment: for now that's what I ended up using (the composition instead of the heritage). 
But I had to re-implement all the method of int, since I wanted to keep the clean interface. So more than 50 method. It works well, but I am not really happy with the result, so if anyone has a better idea, I'd be very glad to ear it.

Comment: You can use a method delegation (but modifying dunder getattr) but that wont help for all objects. I think I saw a package with a decorator that added default implementation of the dunder methods where your class is meant to look like a numeric - I will see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, even though it required a lot of work, compared to what I wanted to do. I did the following :

```
class EnhancedInt(int):
"""
Does everything a int can do, but can also be addressed bitwise (you can read, write, 
add and delete a bit at given position)
Bit representation is in little endian : the lowest indexes corresponding to the least 
significant bits
"""
def __init__(self, x: Union[str, bytes, SupportsInt]) -> None:
    int.__init__(int(x))
    self.__value__ = int(x)

def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> int:
    """Returns the digit number *key* from the binary representation of *self* (little endian)
    Args:
        key (int): bit number to be returned
    Returns:
        int: value of the bit addressed
    """
    EnhancedInt._check_key_value(key)
    return (self.__value__ >> key) & 1

def __setitem__(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
    """Changes the value of the *key*th bit of *self* (little endian)
    Args:
        key (int): index of bit to be modified
        value (int): bit value (must be 0 or 1)
    """
    EnhancedInt._check_key_value(key)
    if value != 0 and value != 1:
        raise ValueError("Value must be 0 or 1, %d given" % value)
    if (not self[key]) and value:
        self.__value__ += 1 << key
        return None
    if self[key] and not value:
        self.__value__ -= 1 << key
```

I also redefines all the methods used for the class int.
This method seems overkill, and has other flaws. I'd like to find a more elegant way, but meanwhile, this will to.
The complete code can be found at the following address : https://github.com/assombrance/Quantomatic/blob/master/src/data.py

Comment: There is no point in having this class inherit from `int`. The inherited `int` structure will desynchronize from the `__value__` attribute as soon as a `__setitem__` is performed, and anything that actually uses the inherited structure will use the wrong value.